# Express the trigonometric identity $\cos nx$ as an infinite series of $\sin^2 x/2$.

Tags: trigonometry

The trigonometric identity $\cos nx$ is expressed as an infinite series only in terms of $\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$ as follows.
$$ \cos nx = 1 + \sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^l \frac{2^{2l}}{(2l)!} \prod_{k=0}^{l-1} (n^2 - k^2) \sin^{2l} \frac{x}{2}$$
This is given in the literature but the authors have not provided any proof to this equation. I have tried the proof using the Euler formula and Binomial theorem, but could not succeed. Can anyone please provide the proof for this equation, or at least a guide on how to prove this ?

Thank You.

Comment: I have a doubt (and I can be wrong). Could you give a link for this identity ? Could it be $\sin^{2k} \frac x 2$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The identity is given in the book titled "Numerical Computation of Internal and External Flows - The Fundamentals of Computational Fluid Dynamics" second edition, by Charles Hirsch, in chapter 8, page no. 351.

Comment: This is not an infinite series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) verify $T_n(\cos x) = \cos nx$. This means that $\cos nx$ can be written as a finite sum of powers of $\cos x$. Now simply use the identity $\cos x = 1-2\sin^2(x/2)$ to obtain that $\cos nx$ is a polynomial of $\sin^2(x/2)$.

Comment: Thank You. Following your suggestion, I have selected a suitable explicit expression for the generation of Chebyshev polynomials and after the simplification you mentioned, I got the desired result. However, there was no proof nor any reference for the explicit expression. Can you please comment on this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean no proof for the explicit expression? You refer to the Chebyshev polynomials? Any explicit formula may be proved by the recurrence relation found in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

In the book *"Numerical Computation of Internal and External Flows - The Fundamentals of Computational Fluid Dynamics"* second edition, by Charles Hirsch [chapter $8$, page $351$], equation $(8.1.46)$ is exactly written as
$$\cos (m\phi) = 1 + \sum_{l=1}^m (-)^l \frac{2^{2l}}{(2l)!} \prod_{k=0}^{l-1} (m^2 - k^2) \sin ^{2 l}\left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)$$ and, as I wrote in a early comment, I have problems with it. As you wrote, I assume that $(-)^l$ stands for $(-1)^l$ which gives the formula in the post.

It works for $m=1$. But let us try it for $m=2$; hoping that I am not mistaken, the rhs write
$$1-8 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)+8 \sin ^8\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$$ while using $t=\sin \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$
$$\cos(2\phi)=1-8t^2+8t^4$$

In short, I do not understand.

**Edit**

Written as
$$\cos (m\phi) = 1 + \sum_{l=1}^m (-1)^l \frac{2^{2l}}{(2l)!}\sin ^{2 l}\left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right) \prod_{k=0}^{l-1} (m^2 - k^2) $$ Using Pochhammer symbols
$$\prod_{k=0}^{l-1} (m^2 - k^2)=-(-1)^l m^2 (1-m)_{l-1} (m+1)_{l-1}$$ and the summation is 
$$\cos \left(2 m \sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)\right)\right)-1$$

Comment: The sine term is outside the product series term. So, upon expanding the summation series, only one term appears per expanded term.